# Subparsers Limit Number of Optional Arguments

Tags: python, argparse

I'm using subparsers and I'd like to limit the number of optional arguments passed in when using the command line. The code is below.

```
parser_data_management = subparsers.add_parser('dm', help='data management help')
  parser_data_management.set_defaults(which="dm")
  parser_data_management.add_argument('-delete', '--delete', nargs="+", "Delete index, snapshot, or repository. Optional: If deleting an index, specify fields or log type to delete.")
  parser_data_management.add_argument('-close', '--close', nargs="+", "Close index or indices. Optional: specify fields or log type to close.")
  parser_data_management.add_argument('-open', '--open', nargs="+", "Open index or indices")
  parser_data_management.add_argument('-restore', '--restore', nargs="+", "Restore snapshot")
  parser_data_management.add_argument('-save', '--save', nargs="+", "Create snapshot or repository")
  parser_data_management.add_argument('-compress', '--compress', nargs="+", "Shrink index")
  parser_data_management.add_argument('--watcher', '--watcher', nargs="+", "Create a watcher")
```

From my understanding, the user could potentially add all of the options in one command line call, which I don't want. So, when selecting the "dm" option, I'd like to limit the user so that they can only choose one of the arguments. Is this possible through argparse, or would I have to create my own function for that?

Comment: Use a mutually exclusive group.

Comment: Those look like they could be subcommands of the `dm` subcommand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As hpaulj said in his comment you should use subparser the following way:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
group.add_argument('-delete', '--delete', action='store_true')
group.add_argument('-close', '--close',action='store_true')

print parser.parse_args()
```

EDIT=====(using your initial example)

```
import argparse

def inputparser():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='data management help')
    subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()
    parser_data_management = subparsers.add_parser('dm', help='data management help')
    parser_data_management.set_defaults(which="dm")
    group = parser_data_management.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
    group.add_argument('-delete', '--delete', nargs="+", help="Delete index, snapshot, or repository. Optional: If deleting an index, specify fields or log type to delete.")
    group.add_argument('-close', '--close', nargs="+", help="Close index or indices. Optional: specify fields or log type to close.")
    group.add_argument('-open', '--open', nargs="+", help="Open index or indices")
    group.add_argument('-restore', '--restore', nargs="+", help="Restore snapshot")
    group.add_argument('-save', '--save', nargs="+", help="Create snapshot or repository")
    group.add_argument('-compress', '--compress', nargs="+", help="Shrink index")
    group.add_argument('--watcher', '--watcher', nargs="+", help="Create a watcher")

    print parser_data_management.parse_args()
inputparser()
```

Nothe the (required=True) in group definition, that will force you to use only one of the arguments. None of the arguments should be required=True or it will result in an error.

Comment: thank you! should 'subparser_dm.add_mutually_exclusive_group()' be 'subparser_post.add_mutually_exclusive_group()'? subparser_dm is not defined

Comment: sorry I updated my example with argparse and mutually_exclusive_group, note that you should put required=True in the group definition if you only want to be able to use one argument from the group only.